# Non-existent physical address error with malloc

Tags: c, string, malloc

I'm trying to figure out how to use malloc correctly in C, and have run into an error that I'm having trouble with.

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {

    char * str;

    str = (char *)malloc(10);

    str = "Hello World";

    str[0] = 'R';

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

My Valgrind output:

```
==23136== Process terminating with default action of signal 10 (SIGBUS)
==23136==  Non-existent physical address at address 0x100000F92
==23136==    at 0x100000F66: main (test.c:12)
```

I know that the issue is due to me trying to allocate the letter 'R' to `str`, but I was under the impression that the advantage of using `malloc` in this situation (as opposed to `char str[10] = "Hello World"`), was the ability to edit the contents of my string.

Thanks!

Comment: what is length of string `Hello World`? It's more then you actually allocate and you have to copy string using `strcpy`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`str = "Hello World";` makes `str` point to a constant char string "Hello World", and the memory you have malloced will become memory leak.

Comment: Also, the crash is due to attempt to write to a string literal

Answer (score 1):

You copy a string with `strcpy` from `<string.h>`, not by re-assigning a pointer.

But take care that the target buffer will actually hold `strlen(source) + 1` characters (0-terminator). `"Hello World"` is 11+1.

Also, trying to modify that improperly assigned string literal is UB.

Anyway, [Don't cast the result of malloc (and friends)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845).

Finally, `return EXIT_SUCCESS` is superfluous (since C99 `main` has an implicit `return 0;` at the end).

Comment: The implicit `return 0;` is only available since C99.

Comment: @YuHao: Yes... Added reference to minimum standard.

Comment: `stdlib.h` is required for `malloc`

Answer (score 0):

You are throwing away the return value of `malloc`. Instead you are setting it to a value in read only memory

Try replacing

```
str = "Hello World";
```

with

```
strcpy(str, "Hello World");
```

You will need to include the appropriate header file

Comment: If doing this then OP needs to allocate more than 10 bytes

Comment: @MattMcNabb - I did not bother to count the characters so you right